# Where in Scripture, did it mention the fallen relationship between God and Satan?

Tags: satan

I have once heard that, in someone's remarks, stated that, "Satan was a beautiful angel and was created by God. Later, He became jealous of God and was cast out of Heaven". However, I haven't find any valid passage that support this claim. Perhaps someone can guide me to a correct path of my research.

Comment: Many traditional notions about angels and demons and heaven and hell come from less-known scriptures such as [Enoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch). Which scriptures are factual is a separate matter altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another place in the Old Testament that talks about the fall of Lucifer:

> KJV Ezekiel 28
> 12 Son of man, take up a lamentation upon the king of Tyrus, and say unto him, Thus saith the Lord GOD; Thou sealest up the sum, full of wisdom, and perfect in beauty.
> 13 Thou hast been in Eden the garden of God; every precious stone was thy covering, the sardius, topaz, and the diamond, the beryl, the onyx, and the jasper, the sapphire, the emerald, and the carbuncle, and gold: the workmanship of thy tabrets and of thy pipes was prepared in thee in the day that thou wast created.
> 14 Thou art the anointed cherub that covereth; and I have set thee so: thou wast upon the holy mountain of God; thou hast walked up and down in the midst of the stones of fire.
> 15 Thou wast perfect in thy ways from the day that thou wast created, till iniquity was found in thee.
> 16 By the multitude of thy merchandise they have filled the midst of thee with violence, and thou hast sinned: therefore I will cast thee as profane out of the mountain of God: and I will destroy thee, O covering cherub, from the midst of the stones of fire.
> 17 Thine heart was lifted up because of thy beauty, thou hast corrupted thy wisdom by reason of thy brightness: I will cast thee to the ground, I will lay thee before kings, that they may behold thee.
> 18 Thou hast defiled thy sanctuaries by the multitude of thine iniquities, by the iniquity of thy traffick; therefore will I bring forth a fire from the midst of thee, it shall devour thee, and I will bring thee to ashes upon the earth in the sight of all them that behold thee.
> 19 All they that know thee among the people shall be astonished at thee: thou shalt be a terror, and never shalt thou be any more.

In Isaiah, Lucifer was typified by the king of Babylon, here in Ezekiel, God uses King of Tyre as a type to explain what happened to Lucifer.

Several points that clearly show that this is talking about Lucifer and not the literal King of Tyre:

1. He was in Eden, the garden of God - only Lucifer was in Eden, tempting Eve in the form of serpent
2. Anointed Cherub that covereth - this refers to the two cherubs that cover the ark of covenant. Lucifer was one of the two.
3. Reason of thy brightness - referring to the brightness that surrounds angels.

Revelation talks about the fall of Lucifer:

> KJV Revelation 12:7-10 And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels, And prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven.
> And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him.  And I heard a loud voice saying in heaven, Now is come salvation, and strength, and the kingdom of our God, and the power of his Christ: for the accuser of our brethren is cast down, which accused them before our God day and night.

The Bible says there was war in heaven and Satan was defeated and was cast down

Comment: where did it state that Satan was a angel of the LORD and was the "Angel of Worship"?

Comment: Not one that covered the ark of the covenant. Other cherubs are mentioned that are around the throne. It is believed he was the one which covered the throne. Also, the Bible never calls the Cherubs angels, we do.

Answer (score 4):

The passage you mention is Isaiah 14

> 12 How you have fallen from heaven, O day star, son of the dawn!
> You have been cut down to the ground, O destroyer of nations.
> 13 You said in your heart: “I will ascend to the heavens; I will raise my throne above the stars of God. I will sit on the mount of assembly, in the far reaches of the north.
> 14 I will ascend above the tops of the clouds; I will make myself like the Most High.”
> 15 But yo will be brought down to Sheol, to the lowest depths of the Pit.

There's some renderings that make this refer to Lucifer (aka The Devil). Jesus then says this in Luke 10:18, which seems to reinforce this idea

> 18 So He told them, “I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven.

[It's debatable if that's what this actually refers to](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/8068/40768), since the overall idea there is that Isaiah is talking to the "King of Babylon" (Is 14:4)

> I am not aware of a tradition before Jesus that sees Satan in Isaiah 14:12